# Why is Nuxt 3 / Vite adding import statement "createError" to locally imported dependency - Error on client execution

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vite, nuxtjs3

### Intentional Task

Add a vue 3 plugin to a nuxt 3 project, orchestrated by a yarn monorepo and local package dependency

```
nuxt 3.6.5
nuxi 3.6.6
nitro 2.5.2
vue ^3
typescript
yarn 3.5.1
```

### Project Overview

There is a monorepo with yarn workspaces "frontend" and "vue-plugin-a". "frontend" is a nuxt 3 application and imports **local** vue 3 plugin dependency "vue-plugin-a". It is added as a plugin `vue-plugin-a.client.ts` to the nuxt project and used in a SFC like so:

##### sfc.vue

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { StuffComponent } from "vue-plugin-a";
</script>
<template>
   <StuffComponent token="hello" />
</template>
```

##### package.json (workspace frontend)

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "nuxt dev",
   ...

"dependencies": {
   "vue-plugin-a": "workspace:vue-plugin-a",
   "vuetify": ...

"devDependencies": {
   "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
   "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
   "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
   "@vueuse/core": "^10.2.1",
   "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.2.1",
   "eslint": "^8.45.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
   "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
   "vue-tsc": "^1.8.6",
   ...
```

##### ts.config (workspace frontend)

```
{
    // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
    "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
    // project context
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "ignore": ["node_modules/**/*", ".yarn/**"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        },
        "types": ["@nuxt/types"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "output"]
}
```

##### package.json (workspace vue-plugin-a)

```
   "scripts": {
      "build": "run-p type-check build-only build:tsc",
      "build:tsc": "vue-tsc --emitDeclarationOnly -p tsconfig.json --composite false",
      "build-only": "vite build",
      "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json --composite false",
       ...
   "peerDependencies": {
        "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
        "vue": "^3"
    },
```

##### browser client debugging

**Browser - error invalid index.es.js | dist folder of plugin in monorepo is correctly resolved**

[image: Browser - error invalid index.es.js]
[image: Browser - falsy additional import statements from nuxt and vite - broken "createError"]
[image: Browser - error invalid index.es.js]

**VSC - builded esmodul of vue-plugin-a into `/dist/index.es.js`**

[image: Builded ESModul of vue-plugin-a`]

##### Error

Nuxt adds an import statement for "createError" but the builded esmodul of the ´vue-plugin-a´ has already a function definition within. There is **no** manually written function `createError" in the scope of` vue-plugin-a`, so it is added by vue or vite during build process. **Important notice:** These import statements are not added, when the package is imported via npm as node_modules!

##### Question to solve

Why is Nuxt / vite (?) adding these import statements for local esmodules, either in `/public/index.es.js` or `workspace/dist/index.es.js`, while the same builded plugin via npm doesn't receive these imports? How can I prevent this circumstance?

Any hints or feedback are highly appreciated.
Thank you SO community